# Shopware 6 add customfield set to cms-element

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I was wondering if there is a way to map custom fields (e.g. from product) in custom cms-elements?

I added some custom fields to the product entity.
Now I'm trying to add them to the demovalue. Since I'm completely new to vue I don't know how to start.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say without knowing what your current code is and what the element should look like exactly.

For a simple example, have a look at how the "Product name" element is registered.

It is registered [here](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/ad2234f3f4f95f72a392cf9051d9f1b7f29b30e5/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-cms/elements/product-name/index.js). The actual mapping of the product name happens within the [component of the element](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/ad2234f3f4f95f72a392cf9051d9f1b7f29b30e5/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-cms/elements/product-name/component/index.js#L23) though.

```js
this.element.config.content.source = 'mapped';
this.element.config.content.value = 'product.name';
```

Set the content source of the element to be `mapped`.
For the content value you'll provide a path to the field. In case of a custom field: `product.customFields.technical_name_of_a_custom_field`

Comment: There isn't any existing code yet. I'm just trying to get a technical understating.

For now, I just want to extend the data mapping list in the cms-element config. custom fields are not shown in that list.